# Webgl program not displaying shape when run in browser

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I'm learning how to work with shaders and I'm currently trying to write a vertex and fragment shaders for a cartoon-style shape. I have example code for a sphere that is colored in, which works properly, so I copied the structure from that file into the one I'm creating. However, when I run my file, only a black background appears on the page without the shape being displayed. I tried comparing the two files to make sure that I had all of the boiler plate code and it seems so, but as I'm extremely new to computer graphics programming, there is probably something important that I'm leaving out. What does my program doing incorrectly or what should be added to it? The code for the program is below:

```
<script src=lib1.js></script>
<body bgcolor=black>
<center>
<canvas id='canvas1' width='600' height='600'>
</canvas>
</center>
</body>


<script id='vs' type='other'>
   uniform vec3 lightDir;
   varying float intensity;
   void main(){
       vec3 ld;
       intensity = dot(lightDir, gl_Normal);
       gl_Position = ftransform();
   }
</script>


<script id='fs' type='other'>
varying float intensity;
void main(){
    vec4 color;
    if(intensity > 0.95)
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    else if(intensity > 0.5)
        color = vec4(0.6, 0.3 , 0.3, 1.0);
    else if(intensity > 0.25)
        color = vec4(0.4 , 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
    else color = vec4(0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = color;
    }
</script>


<script>
start_gl("canvas1", getStringFromScript('vs'), getStringFromScript('fs'));
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of library are you using ? I dont see a definition for the `ftransform` function you're calling in your vertex shader

Comment: @LJᛃ I didn't notice the fact that the line required another library. I found the code online in a fragment shader example. That is probably why the shape isn't showing up. Now I just need to find a way to implement a new fragment shader with the code js code I have.

Comment: A look into the dev console should've shown you an error message when compiling your shader.

Comment: The shader you found looks like it came from an old version of full OpenGL. WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0. Both `gl_Normal` and `ftransform()` were built-ins in older versions of OpenGL (and still are in the compatibility profile of full OpenGL).

Answer (score 1):

As @Reto eluded to in the comments there's no such thing as `gl_Normal` or `fTransform` in WebGL. Those are from old desktop OpenGL. They are not part of OpenGL ES 2.0 which is what WebGL is based on

[Maybe you should start lower level](http://webglfundamentals.org)